# App Engine Endpoint: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: google-app-engine, url, get, google-cloud-endpoints

Following is my App Engine Endpoint. I annotate it as `ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET` because I want to be able to make a get call through the browser. The class itself has a few dozen methods understandably. Some of them using `POST`. But `getItems` is annotated with `GET`. When I try to call the url through a browser, I get a 405 error

```
Error: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

The code:

```
@Api(name = "myserver", 
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "thecompany.com", ownerName = "thecompany", packagePath = ""), 
        version = "1", description = "thecompany myserver", defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE
```

)
         public class myserver {

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getItems", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET) 
public CollectionResponse<Item> getItems(@Named("paramId") Long paramId) {     
    …     
    return CollectionResponse.<Item>builder().setItems(ItemList).build();     
}

}
```

This is not for localhost, it’s for the real server. Perhaps I am forming the url incorrectly. I have tried a few urls such as

```
https://thecompanymyserver.appspot.com/_ah/spi/com.thecompany.myserver.endpoint.myserver.getItems/v1/paramId=542246400

https://thecompanymyserver.appspot.com/_ah/spi/myserver/NewsForVideo/v1/542246400
```

Comment: why is it so difficult to format SO code nowadays? It used to be so easy. They ever they `fix` they need to change it back.

Comment: you could use the api explorer to find out whether you're using the correct url. Go to https://yourprojectid.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer . Also if you're not planning to use the google javascript api client you should add `path=...` to your `@ApiMethods`, so you are sure about what the path actually is.

Answer (score 1):

The proper path for this is **/_ah/api/myserver/1/getItems**. /_ah/spi refers to the backend path, which only takes POST requests of a different format.

Side note: API versions are typical "vX" instead of just "X".

Comment: All of these have failed: `https://myprojectid.appspot.com/_ah/api/myserver/1/getItems/?itemid=234561778737373333`, and

`https://myprojectid.appspot.com/_ah/api/myserver/1/getItems/234561778737373333`, and

`https://myprojectid.appspot.com/_ah/api/myserver/1/getItems/itemid/234561778737373333`

Comment: You should be able to use API explorer to make a test request, which will show the URL you need. Try removing the ending slash from the first URL, though. Would be helpful to know what error you're getting now. Shouldn't be 405.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the api explorer to find out whether you're using the correct url. Go to

```
https://yourprojectid.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer
```

this works on the devserver as well:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer
```

Also if you're not planning to use the google javascript api client you should add `path="..."` to your `@ApiMethod`s, so you are sure about what the path actually is.

Comment: api explorer does not provide any detail. It shows the name of my server, but when I click on it nothing happens: not expanding, nothing.

Comment: @learner The API explorer looks indeed a bit broken today. Try the following: Go to `<server>/_ah/api/explorer`. Click the API and if nothing happens the URL should be correct so click into the URL and simply press Enter. It now should list your endpoint methods. Select one and press `Execute` and you should see the correct Endpoint URL.